# space is not consider in command line argument in java

Tags: java

I am implementing one program in which i am providing command line argument as input.

I have added argument in Eclipse `D:/IBM/Instruction Xmls`
in main method

`String[] args`  args contain two element

```
args[0]=D:/IBM/Instruction
args[1]=Xmls
```

in this program i am reading path and providing that path to one of method.
but due to above behavior it not working

Is there any special character that can be used instead of space in path so that args[0] will contain whole path. i.e `args[0]=D:/IBM/Instruction Xmls`

i can't modify my path in local system

One solution that i got is i can iterate args array and create string as a path.
but i don't want to do this. is there any other solution in command line only? any special character or operator?

Comment: That is intended behavior. The space is the separator for the arguments. How else would the main method know how to split them?

Comment: Wrap in double quotes?

Comment: @Mena - Ya, that would do it